# bash script for sed command to get data between two string between single or multiple line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have some files(.v.gz). The data is present in the file is shown below

syntax:

```
module **module_name**(out, In, clk, rst )
statement 1
statement 2
   :
   :
statement n
endmodule
```

the actual data is

***file***

```
module mod_reg_lif(out, In, clk, rst )  #
statement 1
statement 2
   :
   :
statement n
endmodule

module 
    dff_reg_net(out, In, clk, rst )  
statement 1
statement 2
   :
   :
statement n
endmodule

module 
   dat_log_out (out, In, clk, rst ) 
statement 1
statement 2
   :
   :
statement n
endmodule

module rest_wire_lib  (out, In, clk, rst ) 
statement 1
statement 2
   :
   :
statement n
endmodule
```

actual file contains similar type of multiple data

```
module switch(in1, datainready1, atainready) 
always @(posedge clk) 
begin 
  if (reset == 1)
  begin 
    counter<= 0;
      datainreadyl<= 0;
    if(counter ==0) 
      dataoutready<= 0;
   end 
endmodule
```

here switch is a module name

The above example please check the module_names are ***mod_reg_lif   ,dat_log_out ,dff_reg_net, rest_wire_lib   ,***

consider after *module* as  *module_name* (in the same line or next line it stars) till *(* occurs if it's in the same line or next line.
in output, I want only module names like this

```
mod_reg_lif   
dat_log_out 
dff_reg_net
rest_wire_lib
```

what output I am getting

```
mod_reg_lif   
rest_wire_lib
```

I am not able to fetch all the data as I mentioned in the output, because both module and module_name are present in the same line.

My bash code is

```
for file in *.v.gz;
do
  zgrep -A1 "^module" "$file" | sed -n -e 's/^\(module \)*\(.*(.*)\).*$/\2/p' | cut -f1 -d"(" > $(basename "$file" .v.gz).txt
done
```

please correct my *sed -n -e 's/^(module )*(.*(.*)).*$/\2/p'* command i am not sure how to fix.

ps: please comment if you have any doubts about the question.

Comment: Can you have parentheses ( `( )` ) anywhere else or will they always be just after the module name? Also, what operating system are you using? Can we assume GNU tools?

Comment: @terdon  yes I am using parentheses for other operations inside the module(statements...). but this will eliminate in the grep step. I am using RedHat Unix

Comment: @terdon  i am considering after **module** everything is **module name** till  first open parentheses. this will repeat

Comment: Thanks. But please don't add comments to the file, the file should be _exactly_ as your real data.

Comment: Does the word `module` appear in other contexts too or can we ignore the stuff in your question about parentheses and just output whatever word follows `module`?

Comment: If we do need to consider the parentheses then could you ever have parens inside the argument list, e.g. `module mod_reg_lif(out, In, (clk), rst )`? If we do need to consider parens then please [edit] your question to include cases where ignoring them would break a script, and if args could be inside parens then also add at least 1 such case of that.

Comment: When you say `after module everything is module name till first open parentheses` - does that mean a module name can include white space? If so, again, [edit] your example to include such a case.

Comment: I see you didn't address my comments but just added a second example which is another block of text (`module switch(in1, datainready1, atainready)...`) that's exactly the same format as the existing blocks of text so that's adding no value, just cluttering up your question. You must have had some reason to add it though (i.e. something you thought your existing example didn't properly convey) so please tell us what that reason was.

Comment: @EdMorton the code that i mentioned in my question its giving how the output how i want. but it's giving output if the module_name and module are present in the same line. if its not present its not giving module_name

Comment: @EdMorton there is no white space in the module_name

Comment: @EdMorton the reason for the second example is, to know the real scenario.

Comment: But isn't it exactly as you already showed in your original example? If there's a difference - what is the difference? Also, you already got an answer that would work for your posted example so why bother adding yet another identically formatted example? Is there something about the currently posted answer that isn't working for you?

Comment: Regarding https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/725869/bash-script-for-sed-command-to-get-data-between-two-string-between-single-or-mul?noredirect=1#comment1376103_725869 - we know the code in your question won't work, why are you mentioning that again in a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you're trying to do, using GNU awk for multi-char `RS`, `RT`, `\<` word boundary, and `\s` shorthand for `[[:space:]]`:

```
$ zcat *.v.gz | awk -v RS='\\<module\\s+[^[:space:](]+' 'RT{$0=RT; print $2}'
mod_reg_lif
dff_reg_net
dat_log_out
rest_wire_lib
```

Comment: It's good if you added some explanation @EdMorton

Comment: We can't explain basic constructs in every answer - please look up whatever it is you don't understand in the man page and then let me know if you have any specific questions about anything and I'll be happy to explain.

Answer (score 2):

From the example you give, it looks like parentheses only occur just after the module name and module names have no whitespace. If so, you could do:

```
$ zgrep -oP '\S+\s*(?=\()' file.v.gz 
mod_reg_lif(
dff_reg_net
dat_log_out 
rest_wire_lib
```

The extra `(` in `mod_reg_lif(` is there because your example has `module mod_reg_lif((out, In, clk, rst )`, which I assume is a typo.

The idea here is to use PCRE mode in grep to get [lookaheads](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) which lets us look for non-whitespace characters (`\S+`) followed by 0 or more whitespace characters (`\s*`) and then a `(` (`(?=\()`).

If you don't have a grep with a `-P` option, you can do:

```
$ zgrep -o '[^[:blank:]]*[[:blank:]]*(' file.v.gz | sed 's/ *(//g'
mod_reg_lif
dff_reg_net
dat_log_out
rest_wire_lib
```

---

If you cannot use the parentheses, if there are other places in your file where parentheses may occur, so you need to use the `module` string to identify module names, you can try:

```
$ zcat file.v.gz | perl -007ne 'print join("\n",(/\bmodule\s*(\S+?)\s*\(/gs)),"\n"; '
mod_reg_lif
dff_reg_net
dat_log_out
rest_wire_lib
```

Note that this will load the entire file into memory which might be an issue for huge files.

---

Finally, you can also use `awk`, setting the record separator to two the empty string which causes awk to work in "paragraph mode" where records (lines) are defined by two consecutive newline characters. Then, remove anything after the first parenthesis on a line and print the second field:

```
$ zcat file.v.gz | awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}{sub(/\(.*/,"");print $2; }'
mod_reg_lif
dff_reg_net
dat_log_out
rest_wire_lib
```

Comment: suppose you can not add **module_name**  because in file almost 1000 **module_name** present @terdon

Comment: @SanthoshNayakD. sorry, I don't understand. What is `module_name`? That isn't mentioned in your question.

Comment: i added a small part of the real code scenario in that **switch** is module_name.  each time module_name will change

Comment: @SanthoshNayakD. yes, but why is that relevant? Both the second and the third solutions should work, right?

Comment: because of $ its gives an error, and it's working perfectly. 2nd code is giving some error value by it's fetching a few comments also @terdon

Comment: @SanthoshNayakD. this works as expected on your example. If your real data are different, please make that clear in your question. I don't know what "because of $ its gives an error" means, and if you have comments, again, then we would need to see that in the file and know what defines a comment.

Comment: @SantoshNayakD the `$` at the start of each command line in the answer is the prompt. You don't type the prompt.

Comment: Oooh! Yes, sorry @SanthoshNayakD. The `$` indicates the shell prompt, it's the character you see when you are about to type something on the command line. When showing both a command and its output, it is common to add the `$` in front of the command so you can visually separate the command from its output.